# MySQL service not found

Tags: mysql, unix, lamp, bitnami, init.d

I am dealing with a frustating problem. I have a CMS website that was working fine and dandy until it couldn't recognize mysql being installed. I have AWS LightSail LAMP Stack by Bitnami.

I can see that mysql is running when I run:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p status
```

I can log into mysql using my username and password.

I tried to also get the status using:

```
sudo service mysqld start
```

It returned
Unit mysqld.service could not be found.

I checked /etc/init.d and mysql is missing from there.

Not sure what caused it to get deleted or removed.

Bitnami dev is saying I cannot reinstall the mysql. If I start a fresh server it's going to be a pain to setup the website due to a lot of custom coded things which are out of my league.

Is there a way to get the service to start or get installed?

I have tried to get the service status by using the two commands above. I could not get any information. I can log into the mysql without issues but the Bitnami LAMP stack does not see that mysql service is running.

Comment: look for the mysql error log there you will find if anything is wrong

Comment: Just checked the log. There is only one warning with CA certificate ca.pem is self signed. Otherwise it says mysql_main config to support TLS and encrypted. Then it shows me the socket and port.

Comment: then it is running which port is it saying?

Comment: Port 3306. I also tried mysql -h localhost -u root -p and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

I changed the hostname from localhost to 127.0.0.1 since its TCP driven. Now my website works. I still tried to get the status of mysql and it still says it cannot be found.